# How can I use or create an onupdate middleware using mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, middleware

With mongoose we can use some middlewares when we manipulate data. For example, this is a famous use of the **save** middleware:

```
Schema.pre('save', function(next){
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
  });
});
```

I would like to know how to do the same when you try to update some records. I read in several forums that can use: `Schema.pre('update')`, I've tried but it doesn't work for me. The idea is to re-encrypt the new password when the user wants to change it. I know than I could do this in the controller, but I would like to take away that responsibility and do it from the schema.

The result must be something like:

```
Schema.pre('onUpdate', function(next){
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ready, I’ve modified it!

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't actually answer the question but if your use-case is to update the password only, you can use the following:

```
let userDetails = await User.findOne({ userID: userIDFromRequest });
userDetails.password = request.newPasswordFromRequest;
await userDetails.save();
```

Without having to worry about the hashing.
Also, if you really need the update hook try the code below (Not tested):

```
UserSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
    let update = this._update;
    if (update.$set && update.$set.password) {
        this.update({}, { password: generateHash(update.$set.password) });
    }
    next();
});
```

You can read more here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes